# Problems using pygame with a gamepad

Tags: python, pygame

Hi i'm using pygame for a school project but it seems to not work correctly.
First of all i try to use it with a gamepad and to make it return me joystick position but even when i use their own program

```
    import pygame

# Define some colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)

# This is a simple class that will help us print to the screen
# It has nothing to do with the joysticks, just outputing the
# information.
class TextPrint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

    def print(self, screen, textString):
        textBitmap = self.font.render(textString, True, BLACK)
        screen.blit(textBitmap, [self.x, self.y])
        self.y += self.line_height

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.line_height = 15

    def indent(self):
        self.x += 10

    def unindent(self):
        self.x -= 10


pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
size = [500, 700]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Initialize the joysticks
pygame.joystick.init()

# Get ready to print
textPrint = TextPrint()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while done==False:
    # EVENT PROCESSING STEP
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done=True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

        # Possible joystick actions: JOYAXISMOTION JOYBALLMOTION JOYBUTTONDOWN JOYBUTTONUP JOYHATMOTION
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Joystick button pressed.")
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Joystick button released.")


    # DRAWING STEP
    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    textPrint.reset()

    # Get count of joysticks
    joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()

    textPrint.print(screen, "Number of joysticks: {}".format(joystick_count) )
    textPrint.indent()

    # For each joystick:
    for i in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
        joystick.init()

        textPrint.print(screen, "Joystick {}".format(i) )
        textPrint.indent()

        # Get the name from the OS for the controller/joystick
        name = joystick.get_name()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Joystick name: {}".format(name) )

        # Usually axis run in pairs, up/down for one, and left/right for
        # the other.
        axes = joystick.get_numaxes()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Number of axes: {}".format(axes) )
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range( axes ):
            axis = joystick.get_axis( i )
            textPrint.print(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(i, axis) )
        textPrint.unindent()

        buttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Number of buttons: {}".format(buttons) )
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range( buttons ):
            button = joystick.get_button( i )
            textPrint.print(screen, "Button {:>2} value: {}".format(i,button) )
        textPrint.unindent()

        # Hat switch. All or nothing for direction, not like joysticks.
        # Value comes back in an array.
        hats = joystick.get_numhats()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Number of hats: {}".format(hats) )
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range( hats ):
            hat = joystick.get_hat( i )
            textPrint.print(screen, "Hat {} value: {}".format(i, str(hat)) )
        textPrint.unindent()

        textPrint.unindent()


    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 20 frames per second
    clock.tick(20)

# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
pygame.quit ()
```

It detect the gamepad but doesn't return me anything buttons/hats/joystick all the value stays at 0.
Even when i try it with my keyboard it detect the device but always return me 0 even when keys are pressed with `pygame.key.get_pressed()`

The problem is that i dont have a gamepad to experiment most of the time,  so i tried with my keyboard to detect key which are pressed but i doesn't work either. My program was :

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
while True:
    print(pygame.key.get_pressed())
    time.sleep(3)
```

But it doesn't matter which keys are pressed the value remains to 0 for all of them

Answer (score 1):

Try going through and initializing all the joysticks **only once** outside of the loop and then remove the code that initializes them that's currently inside the loop. It may be that when you do that it clears-out some sort of input buffer giving you zeroed-out values. But without having a gamepad on hand to test this theory, this is just my guess.

Comment: I update my questions at the end, i dont know if it change something.

Comment: @Vector your keyboard sample code will not work either because you never pump the event queue in that while loop and so `pygame.key.get_pressed()` will always return an identical snapshot of key states.

Comment: Ok thanks i'm pretty new with pygame, so i just need to add 'pygame.event.pump()' in the while loop ?

Comment: Yes. Preferably `pygame.event.get()` which returns a list of events since you should always be looking for the `pygame.QUIT` event regardless.

Comment: It still show me back the same thing but i tried to print the pygame.event.get() and it only show from time to time the event of me using my mouse but never my keyboard